# Automate backup of Azure API management services using Jenkins or any other tool

Tags: powershell, azure, jenkins, automation, backup

Have written multiple Powershell scripts to take backup of AZure API management service. One script calls another and exports all the products and properties to my local machine.

I want to automate this process of backing up everything directly to Bitbucket. To achieve this i have configured Jenkins which is running on a CentOS server but, i don't know how to automate things using it? 
I tried installing the Powershell Plugin on Jenkins but as i have multiple scripts written having dependency on one another, i just can't paste the whole thing as it is and run.

so is there a way i can run this multiple codes on Jenkins Powershell plugin instead of composing one single code and then run it?

Second thing, should Jenkins be installed on my local machine rather than on CentOS server in order to achieve this?

**Or**

if Jenkins has a plugin to link with my Azure account and export services to Bitbucket? (with Powershell codes out of picture)

Is there any other tool / alternative which is little less complicated?

Comment: as far as I know you can just connect to APIM github repo and clone it, and sync it periodically

Comment: Thanks but this only backs up the recent config changes not the whole products and properties...